# Create a Search box to find text on page

Tags: javascript, search

I'm trying to create a search box  using only html, css and javascript that will search my page for text, if matching text is found, the function should highlight the text inside of a span.

I searched around the web(and stackoverflow) and I was unable to find an answer relevant to my needs)

I have an idea of what to do but i get stuck at a certain point. heres what my code looks like so far.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function init(){
    //creates a variable equal to the value entered in the text box
    var lookfor = document.getElementById("q").value
    //splits the whole page into an array or words
    var words = document.body.innerHTML.split(" ");
    ///loops through the array to get each word
    for( var i=0; i<words.length; i++){

    }   
    //This is where I get lost, i dont know how to make it so that what you enter
    //in the textbox(lookfor) matches somthing on the page. it will get highlighted. i
    //was thinking about using the find object, but im new to javascript and dont know 
    //how to properly use find yet.
    if(lookfor == words[i]) //Find()------
    { 
        '<span class="highlight">' + words + '</span>'
    }
    else{
        alert("Sorry, your search returned no results! Please Try again.")
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you doing it for the challenge of it? It doesn't seem necessary to me since most browsers have a built in find function (usually `ctrl+f`)

Comment: im doing it for an assignment in school. well...part of an assignment

Answer (score 0):

Well, part of your problem would be that you're terminating your for loop too early. Should look more like

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function init()
{
    //creates a variable equal to the value entered in the text box
    var lookfor = document.getElementById("q").value
    //splits the whole page into an array or words
    var words = document.body.innerHTML.split(" ");
    ///loops through the array to get each word
    for( var i=0; i<words.length; i++)
    {      
        //This is where I get lost, i dont know how to make it so that what you enter
        //in the textbox(lookfor) matches somthing on the page. it will get highlighted. i
        //was thinking about using the find object, but im new to javascript and dont know 
        //how to properly use find yet.
        if(lookfor == words[i]) //Find()------
        { 
            '<span class="highlight">' + words + '</span>'
        }        
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, ive fixed that issue but im still unable to match the searched word(s) to the text on the page.

Answer (score 0):

So here is a way to do it using the W3.JS JavaScript library (I provided the link to where it is stored on the w3schools browser). The text to search should be inside the  document tags. Seperate with the

object for each item.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="https://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.js"></script>

<body>

<h2>Filter List</h2>

<p>Search for a name in the input field:</p>

<input oninput="w3.filterHTML('#id01', 'li', this.value)" placeholder="Search for names..">

<ul id="id01">
   <li>Some text to search</li>
   <li>Some other text to search</li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Have a good day.